# Using ACL or simple permissions for CakePHP app

Tags: cakephp, acl

I am building a simple website that needs 3 user levels (member, mod, admin) and am currently using ACL that sets permission on a per-group basis. Now, this is all working out fine, but I am wondering if it would not be better to just have a **role** column in the *users* table that would contain a tinyint and go with that.

Why I am considering this is the following. Say I wanted to have an "admin bar" on the top of the page, I'd have to check in which group the user is, but group names can change and are not static, the **role** column would be. This raises the question, is ACL suited for websites that have such a simple permissions scheme?

Comment: And what would be the difference between this `role` column, and what you probably already have, meaning a `group_id` column that is already an int ? By the way, yes, group names are subject to change and that's why we use primary and foreign keys. And these should never change. The CakePHP ACL datatables do not make exception: even if the group names are indeed present in the ARO table, the ACL logic is based on the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny - I just recently wrote a simple Auth for scenarios like that - I called it "Tiny": http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/

It should be pretty much exactly just about what you need.

It does need the roles to be present in the Session Auth, though and that you manage user roles yourself. So you might have to add this to your login method if you want to use multi role Auth.

As you said - the core one is way to powerful and a real overkill for simple use cases.
Just one thing: call the field "role_id" and not "role".

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/watermark86/2010/09/23/user-permissions-based-on-a-routing-prefix

Though acl is the right way but for small/simple cases like urs you can use this